# How to prevent keyframe animation to restart when scrolling again?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a react page, whose main sections's visibility in the viewport are watched by an intersection observer. Once the section is visible by the user, a keyframe is triggered (usually a basic opacity transition from 0 to 1).

The thing is that the keyframes start again each time I scroll back up/down, which is annoying from a ux perspective. How to prevent keyframes animation to trigger again once they have happened?

Here is a code snippet:

```js
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

const reveal = keyframes`
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
`;

const Section = styled.section`
  margin: 64px 0;
`;

const SectionTitle = styled.h3<{ inView: boolean }>`
  opacity: 0;
  animation: ${({ inView }) =>
    inView &&
    css`
      ${reveal} 1s ease forwards
    `};
`;

const Text = styled.p<{ inView: boolean }>`
  opacity: 0;
  animation: ${({ inView }) =>
    inView &&
    css`
      ${reveal} 1.5s ease forwards
    `};
`;


export default function Home() {
  const [about, aboutInView] = useInView();
  const [pricing, pricingInView] = useInView();
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
        <Section ref={about}>
              <SectionTitle inView={aboutInView}>About</SectionTitle>
              <Text inView={aboutInView}>about text</Text>
        </Section>
        <Section ref={pricing}>
          <Text inView={pricingInView}>pricing text</Text>
        </Section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Because the `useInView()` calls are setting `inView` back and forth, you just need to ensure that once it becomes `true`, to not fire again. You can either update the hook with options to only fire once or use a combination of `useRef` and `useMemo` to only change once its true

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the triggerOnce option ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Set {triggerOnce: true} while calling the useInView Hook

```
// Generally 
const [ref, inView, entry] = useInView({ threshold: 0, triggerOnce: true });

// Your Case
const [about, aboutInView] = useInView({ triggerOnce: true });
```